# Killing a windows terminal opened by MobaXTerm

Tags: windows-7, terminal, cmd.exe

So i am using MobaXterm to run weblogic server.  I believe MobaXTerm spawn the terminal in the background. closing the window in MobaXterm doesn't close the terminal ... because when i tried to re-run my server, I faced an error stating that the address is already in use (the address is only being used by the server, thats for sure).

So what should i do to kill such terminals which have been opeened by mobaxterm ?

Answer (score 0):

When you start weblogic by mobaxterm using sh startWeblogic.sh it will not start weblogic in background.The moment you close the window weblogic should shutdown.In only case if you are running it in nohup ie by nohup ./startWeblogic.sh & then only it will run in background. irrespective of you starting weblogic on Mobaxterm or putty if you are not using nohup then process will stop.

You can try below things to confirm it:

1. start weblogic using mobaxterm using sh startWeblogic.sh
2. Now do tail to Admin server logs using another session.
3. Close the first window which is use to start weblogic
4. Now you should see admin server is shutting down in admin server logs